# Get last change timestamp in header response

Tags: plugin-elementapi

I'll be polling an endpoint created with the element-api plugin which will trigger a concourse build. I need to include a timestamp the last time any entry was changed.

So I need something to go in the setHeader function:

`HeaderHelper::setHeader([...])`

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If you've already got a reference to the entry, this should do it:

```
HeaderHelper::setHeader('MyHeader', $entry->dateUpdated);
```